# MIPS - loading value by comparing with a table of values

Tags: operators, compare, addition, mips

Fellow SO users,

I'm hoping someone can share their ideas on how to go about doing this problem.
Lets say, I have a table of values. The table contains two columns, the first col (COL1) has a  specific value associated with it and the second column (COL2) has another value:

The values are all in hexadecimal

```
COL1    COL2
 0       11
 1       90
 2       52
 3       C8
 4       B7
```

Now, what I have to do is, compare the value in one of the registers and if it matches any value from COL1, I have to load another register with the corresponding value from COL2. For example, if I have a value, say, R2 = 1, I will have to load R3 with 90.

The approach that I'm using involves completely avoiding the `lb` instruction (which I'm aiming for);

```
and $r1, $r1, $r0    #Initialise r1 to 0
addi $r1, $r1, 1     #load r1 with 1
beq $r2, $r1, LOAD_1 #Check to see if r2 = 1

and $r1, $r1, $r0
addi $r1, $r1, 2
beq $r2, $r1, LOAD_2

LOAD_1: 
and $r3, $r3, $zero
addi $r3, $r3, 0x52  #Load r3 with 0x52 as per the table

LOAD_2:
Load value into r3 as before.
```

The issue with this is, it will get ridiculously long if I have a huge table. Could someone please suggest a shorter way, if there exists one (with using the `lb` operator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `COL1` sequence is sorted you can perform a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to quickly find a given value.

If the sequence is both sorted in ascending order and doesn't have any gaps or duplicates (i.e. the *x:th* element always equals the *x-1:th* element plus 1) it becomes even easier:

```
if (R2 >= COL1[0] && R2 <= COL1[last_index]) {
    R3 = COL2[R2 - COL1[0]];
}
```